# Ordenar de manera ascendente una lista de personas, primero por apellido, y si hay apellido repetido, por nombre

Tags: python

> Ordenar de manera ascendente, una lista de invitados, primero por apellido, y si hay apellido repetido por nombre.

Llego hasta organizar por apellido, pero necesito luces de cómo identificar en la lista si hay apellidos repetidos en invitados, entonces organizar por nombre.

Llego hasta acá:

```py
invitados=['Laura Montano','Pedro Garcia','Maria Perez','Carlos Perez','Fernando Perez','Ana Caceres']

invitado= input('Ingrese el nombre y apellido de invitado (ejm: Maria Garcia): ')

def agregar_invitado(invitados,invitado):
    
invitados.append(invitados)

    grupo=list()
    i=0
    while i<len(invitados):
        nueva_lista= invitados[i]
        div_invitado=nueva_lista.split()
        grupo.append(div_invitado)
        i=i+1

    ordenar=sorted(grupo , key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(ordenar)
    
agregar_invitado(invitados,invitado)
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

El método usual es formar una llave uniendo los componentes en el orden de importancia.

En este caso, el orden es Apellido-Nombre, y los voy a unir por simple concatenación, de modo que obtengo todos los "Perez" juntos. Como solo los cinco primeros caracteres de la llave son iguales, el ordenamiento se resuelve mirando los siguientes caracteres, que corresponden al nombre.

Formalmente lo hago transformando la lista de nombres en una lista de listas, donde cada sublista contiene `[Nombre, Apellido]`.

Para ordenar uso `sorted()`, usando el parámetro `key=` para decirle como ordenar los elementos. Este parámetro requiere una función de un sólo argumento (el invitado) y debe devolver la llave calculada.

```
invitados=['Laura Montano','Pedro Garcia','Maria Perez','Carlos Perez','Fernando Perez','Ana Caceres']

inter = [persona.split() for persona in invitados]
final = sorted(inter, key=lambda x: x[1]+x[0] )
print(final)
```

produce:

```
[['Ana', 'Caceres'], ['Pedro', 'Garcia'], ['Laura', 'Montano'], ['Carlos', 'Perez'], ['Fernando', 'Perez'], ['Maria', 'Perez']]
```

Si quieres recuperarla como lista de nombres, aplica

```
inv_ordenados = [' '.join(x) for x in final]
print(inv_ordenados)
```

y tendrás

```
['Ana Caceres', 'Pedro Garcia', 'Laura Montano', 'Carlos Perez', 'Fernando Perez', 'Maria Perez']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

También te puede funcionar lo siguiente:

```py
invitados = ['Laura Montano', 'Pedro Garcia', 'Maria Perez', 'Carlos Perez', 
'Fernando Perez', 'Ana Caceres']
invitado = input('Ingrese el nombre y apellido de invitado (ejm: Maria Garcia): ')
lista_nueva = []
invitados.append(invitado)

for item in invitados:
    item_nuevo = item.split(' ')
    lista_nueva.append(' '.join(reversed(item_nuevo)))
    lista_nueva.sort()
    
print(lista_nueva)
```

Lo fundamental está en estas dos líneas:

```py
item_nuevo = item.split(' ')
lista_nueva.append(' '.join(reversed(item_nuevo)))
```

Una ya la tienes hecha, la parte del `split()`, lo siguiente sería reordenar a la inversa la lista para que te ordene por apellido y así lo guardará en la nueva lista, además hace una concatenación entre apellido y nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu respuesta logre terminar el código

Comment: Genial! Acepta la respuesta si te ayudó, así la comunidad sabe que la duda fue resuelta.